# Using the "new" keyword (Java)

Tags: java, oop

I am relatively new to programming in Java and have a minor problem with the object oriented aspect of it. So, let's get to it! I recently wrote a program to find all the prime numbers between 0 and a number, x and where "i" is the prime number. In this program two of the lines were the same as the following.

```
  BigInteger one = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
    one = one.nextProbablePrime();
```

The purpose of these lines was to convert an integer, i into a BigInteger to use utilize the nextProbablePrime method. Looking back upon this, I see that I did not use the keyword "new" and therefor did not create an instance of the BigInteger class, yet the program still compiled and ran without a hitch. Why was the program able to use the nextProbablePrime method, compile and run if an instance of the BigInteger class was not  created? Also, will not creating an object work in other situations and with other classes and methods. Also, will it inhibit me from using the full functionality of the BigInteger class and is it considered good programming practice?

I also rewrote he two lines of code from the above, into the two lines of code, leaving the rest of the program unchanged.

```
BigInteger one = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
    one = one.nextProbablePrime();
```

I changed the first line of the two to include the use of the word "new". As i expected, It ran without a flaw. Going back to my other questions, which one is better? Which one will give me the greatest functionality despite the class or method I'm using and which one is more considered good practice?

To sum up, my questions are:
1. *Which one is correct?*
2. *Which one will work in all situations, despite the class or method I am using?*
3. *Which one is considered good programming practice?*
4. *How does the first one work without creating an object?*

A quick link to the Biginteger class, for those who may want to look at it - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

Comment: To whoever "-1"'d my post, may I ask why you did so? This is merely so I don't make the same mistake next time when posting a question.

Comment: Do one more thing. From the question itself it is clear that you haven't attached source code of classes, so open any class say BigInteger ,eclipse would ask to attach source,go to your Java installation directory say "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45". Now for any issues in the existing code/method always open the class and see what is actually happening in the background

Comment: probably bcoz of long text of your question.In the future try to keep your question simple,short and to the point.By the way I didn't downvoted it :)

Comment: `2. Which one will work in all situations, despite the class or method I am using?`     In the most cases, you will be using the `new` keyword, but in some cases (classes with limited numbers of instances, method with return type of some Object) you won't. Either the method creates it for you or you just store a pointer to an existing Object to it ->  `Object o = new Object` here you have the new keyword      `Object o2 = o` here you haven't got the new keyword, because no new object was created, `o2` is pointing to the same object as `o`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *did* create an instance of the `BigInteger` class.  It's just that the `new` keyword was used somewhere *inside* the implementation of the `BigInteger.valueOf` method.

`BigInteger.valueOf` is generally more efficient.  It can reuse the same `BigInteger` object for some values of `i` -- perhaps 0, or perhaps like `Integer.valueOf(int)`, it goes from -128 to 128.

`BigInteger.valueOf` is called a factory method, and they're frequently recommended.  Among other things, factory methods can have *names*, where constructors can't; they have more control over their implementation; there's lots of good reasons.  In fact, the *very first* suggestion in *Effective Java* is "Consider static factory methods instead of constructors."

If you actually look up the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.valueOf%28long%29) of `BigInteger.valueOf`, you can see that that's what it's doing: it checks if it can reuse a constant value -- `ZERO` or a small positive or negative value -- and failing that, it just goes ahead and calls `new BigInteger(value)`, though it uses an internal private constructor that takes a `long` rather than using `String.valueOf`.

Comment: To be more precise, without looking at it, the method `public static BigInteger valueOf (String value)` probably just returns `return new BigInteger(value);`

Comment: Also known as the [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method) :-)

Comment: @IngoBürk It's slightly more complicated than that.

Comment: @arshajii Yeah, I just looked at it. The idea stays the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

The first method uses a static method from BigInteger. This would be my preference, though both work as well and both do the exact same thing.

the `new` keyword creates an actual instance of an object in the memory. Since the `BigInteger.valueOf(i);` method is static, it does not need an instance of BigInteger (this method itself namely will create a new BigInteger for you).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation:

> public static BigInteger valueOf(long val)
>
> **Returns a BigInteger** whose value is equal to that of the specified
>   long. This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a
>   (long) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used
>   BigIntegers.
>
> Parameters:
>       val - value of the BigInteger to return. Returns:
>       a BigInteger with the specified value.

The method you are calling is returning a new instance of BigInteger

Here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with here, is a static method of the BigInteger class.

This method will return an auto-allocated instance of BigInteger, which is why Louis is correct. `new` was used for you in the `valueOf` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all object is created inside (* maybe not always).

One of the reason to have `valueOf()` method to have possibility to cache BigInteger's in some small range to not waste resources. (Create 1 object with value 5, instead of tons of them).

You have to create object when you call `new` but you may reuse old object in if-statement inside method

Both variants are OK. But it's better to use `valueOf` because you

- don't create unnecessary string.
- have possibility to cahce

Answer (score 0):

To answer all of your questions:

1. Both are 100% correct.
2. Both will work in any reasonable situation.
3. The first method probably has the least overhead (lag).
4. The first method does create an object inside of the function you call, something like this:

   public static BigInteger valueOf(long val) {
       BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger();
       // do something to make val into a BigInteger
       return bigInteger;
   }

So by the time it gets back to your variable it has already used the `new` keyword.